# How can I click on a particular href in the code below

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am in a situation where there are no unique id and there are number of `div`'s under a class. Cssselector and `xpath`'s are so generic that they are not being recognized.

This is what the *Html* looks like:

[image]

This is my code which doesn't work:

```
@Test
    public void NaviToEpisode(){

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("/episode")).click();
    title_episode = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertTrue(title_episode.contains("File uploading"));

}
```

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Any errors?

Comment: It is working now. I had to restart my Eclipse, asked Developers to restart the server and it seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cssSelector, in your case it would be:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#links>div>a").click();
```

If you use Firefox, install [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=search) plugin, then right click on the element you wish to inspect and in menu click on "Inspect with Firebug", once the snippet of your code highlighted right click on it and you should see an option to copy xpath or css.

Comment: Thanks alot for your advice, unfortunately it didnt work though. My code above works perfectly fine in selenium but as soon as i start implementing the same in TestNG framework, it just doesnt work. I have even tried navigate().to("URL"), this doesnt work either.

Comment: It is working now. I had to restart my Eclipse, asked Developers to restart the server and it seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

try this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@href, '/episode/')]")).click();`

Comment: Thanks alot for your advice, unfortunately it didnt work though. My code above works perfectly fine in selenium but as soon as i start implementing the same in TestNG framework, it just doesnt work. I have even tried navigate().to("URL"), this doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="links" . . >` seems to be static I hope it's unique as well. Following css selector can be used to select first link (i.e. /episodes/)

```
#links div:nth-child(1) a
```

Similarly you can use css selectors to select sub-sequent elements. For example to select 2nd element:

```
#links div:nth-child(2) a
```

So instead of using `By.linkText("/episode")`, use `By.cssSelector("#links div:nth-child(1) a")`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your advice, unfortunately it didnt work though. My code above works perfectly fine in selenium but as soon as i start implementing the same in TestNG framework, it just doesnt work. I have even tried navigate().to("URL"), this doesnt work either.

Comment: It is working now. I had to restart my Eclipse, asked Developers to restart the server and it seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks once again!